# how to compile monitor of cuckoosandbox?

Tags: cross-compiling

I compile monitor on win10(64bit) cygwin ,use i686-w64-mingw32-gcc-4.8.0-win64_rubenvb and x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc-4.8.0-win64_rubenvb,

the error is :

```
src/hooking.c:908:5: error: unknown type name 'IMAGE_DELAYLOAD_DESCRIPTOR'
     IMAGE_DELAYLOAD_DESCRIPTOR *did = NULL;
     ^
src/hooking.c:939:25: error: 'IMAGE_DELAYLOAD_DESCRIPTOR' undeclared (first use in this function)
                 did = *(IMAGE_DELAYLOAD_DESCRIPTOR **)(target + 1);
                         ^
src/hooking.c:939:25: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
src/hooking.c:939:54: error: expected expression before ')' token
                 did = *(IMAGE_DELAYLOAD_DESCRIPTOR **)(target + 1);
                                                      ^
src/hooking.c:953:66: error: request for member 'DllNameRVA' in something not a structure or union
         library_from_asciiz((const char *) h->module_handle + did->DllNameRVA,
                                                                  ^
make: *** [Makefile:80：objects/x86/src/hooking.o] 错误 1
```

I search IMAGE_DELAYLOAD_DESCRIPTOR in winnt.h and delayimp.h,but there is no IMAGE_DELAYLOAD_DESCRIPTOR.

should I use x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc-**4.9.0**-win64_rubenvb or x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc-**4.9.1**-win64_rubenvb or **other version**?

Comment: the key is to find the right compiler,otherwise only Solve a temporary problem .

Answer (score 0):

Please have another look at [winnt.h](https://github.com/wine-mirror/wine/blob/master/include/winnt.h). `IMAGE_DELAYLOAD_DESCRIPTOR` is most certainly defined there, with the following structure:

```
typedef struct _IMAGE_DELAYLOAD_DESCRIPTOR
{
    union
    {
        DWORD AllAttributes;
        struct
        {
            DWORD RvaBased:1;
            DWORD ReservedAttributes:31;
        } DUMMYSTRUCTNAME;
    } Attributes;

    DWORD DllNameRVA;
    DWORD ModuleHandleRVA;
    DWORD ImportAddressTableRVA;
    DWORD ImportNameTableRVA;
    DWORD BoundImportAddressTableRVA;
    DWORD UnloadInformationTableRVA;
    DWORD TimeDateStamp;
} IMAGE_DELAYLOAD_DESCRIPTOR, *PIMAGE_DELAYLOAD_DESCRIPTOR;
```

Best of luck.

Comment: thanks,this is right，can figure out this problem; but can't find the right compiler, will have same type problems, I want find the right compiler;

Comment: [Look here](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.9/changes.html) for the release notes for gcc 4.9.0. [Look here](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/buglist.cgi?bug_status=RESOLVED&resolution=FIXED&target_milestone=4.9.1) for the list of bugs known to be fixed in gcc 4.9.1. Best of luck.

Comment: thanks all. I figure out the problem in linux.      in ubuntu:
sudo apt-get install mingw-w64 python-pip nasm
sudo pip install sphinx docutils PyYAML
in centos: if can't find mingw,change your /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo
sudo yum install mingw* nasm
sudo pip install sphinx docutils PyYAML